# Remove an HTML element with jQuery after appendTo()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a drop down menu. When a user selects something out of the drop down, it adds this element using jQuery appendTo:

```
<p><input type="text" id="callid" name="callid" placeholder="Call ID" /><a href="#" id="remCid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></p>
```

My problem is, when the glyphicon "X" is clicked, the element is not removed.

However, what baffles me, is if the above code is statically coded in the form (not added from my dropdown jQuery menu), clicking the "X" removes the element.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd6wmp85/)

Comment: Please show the jquery part. You should have used .on() method.

Comment: Delegated event handlers - > **https://jsfiddle.net/fd6wmp85/1/**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fd6wmp85/2/ add the click handler after every appendto  function :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the element `#remCid` doesn't exist in the DOM when the event listener is attached.

You could use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and attach the event handler to a common ancestor that exists at the time. In this case, `document`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2fwtbjqw/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#remCid', function() {
    $(this).parents('p').remove();
});
```

---

It doesn't *need* to be attached to the `document` object.

For instance, attaching it to `.more-fields` would also work:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/oenzwt5p/)

```
$('.more-fields').on('click', '#remCid', function () {
    $(this).parents('p').remove();
});
```

As an alternative to event delegation, you could also attach the event listener *after* the element is appended. This may lead to logical errors, though, since multiple event listeners *may* be attached.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up, how could I use this for removing multiple elements? i.e. if I have #remCid, #remCid1, #remCid2, rather than copy/pasting your example (the original) three different times, and changing the div id.

Comment: @jaredwins [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/83jL8crz/). It's worth pointing out that an `id` *must* be unique within a document. Therefore you could use class instead. https://jsfiddle.net/83jL8crz/

Answer (score 0):

to remove append element , you must use

```
delegate jquery event handler 

$(document).delegate('#remCid', 'click', function(){

    $(this).parents('p').remove();

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd6wmp85/3/)